# Why is onInput not a function? A question about useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am pretty new to react and hooks, and I'm struggling with `useEffect()`.  I've watched all the vids and read all the docs and still can't quite wrap my head around the error I'm getting. ("onInput is not a function" when my New Article route loads). onInput points to a callback function in my `form-hook.js`.  Why isn't it registering?

In my `input.js` component:

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';

import { validate } from '../../util/validators';
import './Input.css';

const inputReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        value: action.val,
        isValid: validate(action.val, action.validators)
      };
    case 'TOUCH': {
      return {
        ...state,
        isTouched: true
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const Input = props => {
  const [inputState, dispatch] = useReducer(inputReducer, {
    value: props.initialValue || '',
    isTouched: false,
    isValid: props.initialValid || false
  });

  const { id, onInput } = props;
  const { value, isValid } = inputState;

  useEffect(() => {
  console.log(id);
  onInput(id, value, isValid)

}, [id, value, isValid, onInput]);

  const changeHandler = event => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'CHANGE',
      val: event.target.value,
      validators: props.validators
    });
  };

  const touchHandler = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'TOUCH'
    });
  };

  //if statement to handle if you are updating an article and touch the category.... but it's valid


  const element =
    props.element === 'input' ? (
      <input
        id={props.id}
        type={props.type}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        onBlur={touchHandler}
        value={inputState.value}
      />
    ) : (
      <textarea
        id={props.id}
        rows={props.rows || 3}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        onBlur={touchHandler}
        value={inputState.value}
      />
    );

  return (
    <div
      className={`form-control ${!inputState.isValid && inputState.isTouched &&
        'form-control--invalid'}`}
    >
      <label htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</label>
      {element}
      {!inputState.isValid && inputState.isTouched && <p>{props.errorText}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

`useEffect(() => {onInput` points to the onInput prop in `NewArticle.js` component where users can enter a new article.

```
import Input from '../../shared/components/FormElements/Input';
import { useForm } from '../../shared/hooks/form-hook';

const NewArticle = () => {
 const [formState, inputHandler] = useForm({
title: {
        value: '',
        isValid: false
      }
}, false );
    return (
                <Input
                id="title"
                element="input"
                type="text"
                label="Title"
                onInput={inputHandler}
              /> );
};

export default NewArticle;
```

...and then in my `form-hook.js` inputHandler is a callback. So, onInput points to a callback function through a prop.  It was working, registering onInput as a function and then, all of a sudden it was throwing an error. What gives?

```
import { useCallback, useReducer } from 'react';

const formReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INPUT_CHANGE':
            let formIsValid = true;
            for (const inputId in state.inputs) {
                if (!state.inputs[inputId]) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (inputId === action.inputId) {
                    formIsValid = formIsValid && action.isValid;
                } else {
                    formIsValid = formIsValid && state.inputs[inputId].isValid;
                }
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                inputs: {
                    ...state.inputs,
                    [action.inputId]: { value: action.value, isValid: action.isValid }
                },
                isValid: formIsValid
            };
        case 'SET_DATA':
            return {
                inputs: action.inputs,
                isValid: action.formIsValid
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const useForm = (initialInputs, initialFormValidity) => {
    const [formState, dispatch] = useReducer(formReducer, {
        inputs: initialInputs,
        isValid: initialFormValidity
    });

    const inputHandler = useCallback((id, value, isValid) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'INPUT_CHANGE',
            value: value,
            isValid: isValid,
            inputId: id
        });
    }, []);

    const setFormData = useCallback((inputData, formValidity) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'SET_DATA',
            inputs: inputData,
            formIsValid: formValidity
        });
    }, []);

    return [formState, inputHandler, setFormData];
};
```

Thanks, ya'll.

Comment: Got a question after your edit: Where are formState and setFormData defined? useForm doesn't seem to create them anywhere.

Comment: Sorry was trying to condense for space.  See the full form-hook

Comment: Please upload your code to stackblitz.com or similar service, because I've copied code you provided and it works for me

Comment: Just in case this is an option, `Formik` handles a lot of this for you (isValid, touched, etc).

Comment: Thanks @Barryman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you some advice on how to restructure your code. This will ultimately solve your problem.

1. Maintain a single source of truth

   - The current state of your UI should be stored in a single location.
   - If the state is shared by multiple components, your best options are to use a reducer passed down by the Context API (redux), or pass down the container component's state as props to the Input component (your current strategy).
   - This means you should remove the `Input` component's `inputReducer`.
   - The `onInput` prop should update state in the container component, and then pass down a new `inputValue` to the `Input` component.
   - The DOM `input` element should call `onInput` directly instead of as a side effect.
   - Remove the `useEffect` call.
2. Separation of Concerns

   - Actions should be defined separately from the hook. Traditionally, actions are a function that returns an object which is passed to dispatch.
   - I am fairly certain that the useCallback calls here are hurting performance more than helping. For example `inputHandler` can be restructured like so:

```js
  const inputChange = (inputId, value, isValid) => ({
                        type: 'INPUT_CHANGE',
                        value,
                        isValid,
                        inputId
                      })

  export const useForm = (initialInputs, initialFormValidity) => {
                           const [formState, dispatch] = useReducer(formReducer, {
                             inputs: initialInputs,
                             isValid: initialFormValidity,
                           })

                           const inputHandler = (id, value, isValid) => dispatch(
                                                  inputChange(id, value, isValid)
                                                )
                         }
```

3. Learn how to use `debugger` or breakpoints in the browser. You would quickly be able to diagnose your issue if you put a breakpoint inside your `useEffect` call.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy.  This is very useful.