# Uncaught TypeError: onInput is not a function React@18.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and watching some tutorials about useReducer and decided to integrate it into my project. The tutorial uses React@16.11 and I'm using the latest version which is React@18.2.

I'm trying to use **Input.js** component to use  in the project for validity etc.

**Input.js**

```
// object destructing
  const { id, onInput } = props;
  const { value, isValid } = inputState;

  // useEffect(() => {function that needs to be executed}, [array of dependencies])
  useEffect(() => {
    onInput(id, value, isValid);
  }, [id, value, onInput, isValid]); //whenever these dependencies changes, it will trigger
```

Where I use is **NewPage.js**

```
 <form className="place-form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Input
          id="title"
          element="input"
          type="text"
          label="Name of the company"
          validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]} // check what user entered is not empty
          errortext="Please enter a valid title."
          onInput={inputHandler}
        />
      </form>
```

**form-hook.js**

```
const formReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INPUT_CHANGE":
      let formIsValid = true;

      //go through all the inputs that we have in my form here and check if the all inputs are valid
      for (const inputId in state.inputs) {
        if (!state.inputs[inputId]) {
          continue;
        }

        if (inputId === action.inputId) {
          //looking at the inputs and checking the input that we are currently looking at, the input which is getting updated in (INPUT_CHANGE) in this current action, if that is the case, we will take the information from the dispatch action on wheter is valid or not
          formIsValid = formIsValid && action.isValid;
        } else {
          //if we are looking at an input in form state which is not currenly getting updated thorugh the currenly runnin action
          formIsValid = formIsValid && state.inputs[inputId].isValid; // take the stored value (stored validity) for this input because it is the input we're not currently updating with this action(INPUT_CHANGE)
        }
      }

      //return a new state
      return {
        ...state, //copy the existing state
        inputs: {
          ...state.inputs, //current inputs state
          //overwrite
          [action.inputId]: {
            value: action.value,
            isValid: action.isValid,
          },
        },
        isValid: formIsValid,
      };

        default:
            return state //unchanged state
  }
};


    export const useForm = (initialInputs, initialFormValidity) => {
  const [formState, dispatch] = useReducer(formReducer, {
    inputs: initialInputs,
    isValid: initialFormValidity,
  });

  const inputHandler = useCallback((id, value, isValid) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "INPUT_CHANGE",
      value: value,
      isValid: isValid,
      inputId: id,
    });
  }, []);

 
  return [formState, inputHandler];
};
```

But I'm getting error that says `Input.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: onInput is not a function` even tho I commented that `// useEffect(() => {function that needs to be executed}, [array of dependencies])`

I came up with this solution: [Why is onInput not a function? A question about useEffect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583522/why-is-oninput-not-a-function-a-question-about-useeffect), but the questions asked 2 years ago, and didn't work for me. I believe something to do with version of React.

Full code in here: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/f5oot9fvnVHUDMPb

Many thanks

Comment: Where do you define `inputHandler` in `NewPage.js`?

Comment: Please read how to make a [mre]. So much unessecary time and enery in letting people guess what the code you're not showing is.

Comment: I updated the form-hook.js to show where I define it

Comment: @yuroni we want to see parent of the component what contains your input.

Comment: I'm kinda lost @AlexShtromberg

Comment: I added a plunker for all the files that I use, really new to react and I don't know which one is the parent of the component actually..

Comment: The problem was that the second Input did not receive the props yet, which caused it! Thank you all! For the next project probably I will work with Formik....

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have in **useEffect** dependencies your function, you have more dependencies, and your code doesn't guaranty you that onInput exists anyhow.

As you haven't provide here your full parental code and we can see just small part of it, I can suggest you put **onInput** inside a condition in the **useEffect** handler or put default value to **onInput** inside your props destructor.

```
  // object destructing
  const { id, onInput = () => {} } = props;
  const { value, isValid } = inputState;

  // useEffect(() => {function that needs to be executed}, [array of dependencies])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (onInput) {
      onInput(id, value, isValid);
    }
  }, [id, value, onInput, isValid]); //whenever these dependencies changes, it will trigger
```

Don't use both, it is unreasonable

Comment: It's better to ask OP to clarify the question instead of guessing at a solution. And this is not really a solution either way.

Comment: What about using third party library such as Formik, instead of doing all of these from zero? I believe the tutorial just want to show how can be done like this,  but  efficient way is use Formik nowadays *?

Comment: @yuroni I don't get your comment, aren't you the one who wrote the question? And now you are saying me here to use Formik is more efficient? 